# How can we create a GUI Representation in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, antlr4

I am working on a data mapping project where we take data as an input and apply some rules on it and produce the output.
We have a scenario where we want to show the rules in a graphical representation in the UI.
Could anyone please tell me what are the tools we can use for this.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi Zahid, possible to provide more context of the rules that you're referring to here, e.g. some json schema, or something else, etc.? And what kind of graphical representation are you referring to here, e.g. just a text formatting, graph and nodes, etc.?

Comment: If you want to show charts then you can use charts.js library. You can also use anime.js for custom animation implementation too! Choice is yours about what to do with your data.

Comment: Hi @DriLLFreAK100 we have created our own language using antlr and we will write some rules based on that and convert them into a parse tree. we want to create boxes and link the respectively

Comment: Hi @GaurangDhorda we want to render some shapes dynamically and link could you please tell me if there is any library which can help us